# Failed to compile is displayed on chrome browser

Tags: reactjs, parsing, strict

i had an this error below in the browser when working on a react project, it says failed to compile and the data i was parsing in the Api context is below below in from the browser.how can i get rid of this error
./src/data.js
Line 4:14:  Parsing error: Legacy octal literals are not allowed in strict mode

```
2 |     id:1,
  3 |     title:"Google Pixel - Black",
> 4 |     img:"img\1595035611130_elaine-casap-qgHGDbbSNm8-unsplash.jpg",
    |              ^
  5 |     price:10,
  6 |     company:Google,
  7 |     info:"Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis eum obcaecati dignissimos dolorem ex quos a sit repudiandae cumque exercitationem officia assumenda, fugit non corrupti, itaque vel doloremque eligendi quis?",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in `img` name. You have to **`escape`** octal literals inside a string.

**Change that to:**

```
img:"img\\1595035611130_elaine-casap-qgHGDbbSNm8-unsplash.jpg",
```

Comment: thanks .. ill do that and check

Comment: If helpful then please accept this answer.